# Accessing a character from a string in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

So I'm still trying to figure out how to access the first character of a string from an input from C. The result I am getting is "4194172" for a string of "abcd", which I believe is the address of the whole string itself. I want to be able to output the letter "a". Below you can see the C code (which was given)  and the assembly code that I have written.

*C CODE*

```
extern int count(char *string, char c); 
int main(void)
{
    char s[100];
    char c;
    printf("Enter a string of characters:\n");
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("Enter a character to count:\n");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("\nThe number of %c's in the string %s is %d\n", c, s, 
    count(s,c));
    return 0;
}
```

*ASSEMBLY CODE*

```
.text
.globl _count

_count:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $8, %esp
    movl 12(%ebp), %edx
    movzbl (%edx), %eax
done:
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
    .end
```

Comment: Hi, never put code as an image.  You can copy-paste code as text.  See this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question, Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question.

Comment: Even though Nic edited your question to put the code images inline, you need to edit it again to include the code as text, not an image.

Comment: @Rey: if you post your code as images, we can only look at it. If you post it as text, inside your question, we can copy it and look what happens. **Do not post code as image, only as text.**

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the value returned is the address of the string. To get the first character of the string, use this instead

```
 movl 8(%ebp), %edx
 movzbl (%edx), %eax
```

Comment: That gave me "97" as an output?

Comment: Is that the address of the first character. How would I turn this to an "a"

Comment: 97 is the ASCII code for ‘a’. You can print it as a character instead of a number.

Comment: The C code isn’t expecting a character to be returned, it is expecting a count, so it prints it as a number.

Comment: Can I do incl %eax then movzbl (%eax), %eax to get second character? Also how would I convert the asci value to a character.